# Existence of fundamental solution of fractional laplacian

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes

Does the fundamental solution of $$(-\Delta)^sF(x, y)+ V(x) F(x, y)= \delta_{y}(x) \text{ in } \mathbb R^N $$ exist. Here $V(x)$ is a positive smooth non-constant bounded function which satisfy $V(x)\geq c>0$ for all $x\in \mathbb R^N$ and $s\in (0, 1)$ and $N>2s$.

Comment: I do not know a reference for the fractional Laplacian in full space; you may like to look at [Kaleta–Kulczycki, PotA, 2010](http://prac.im.pwr.edu.pl/~tkulczyc/IUSchrodinger.pdf) for some references. There are, however, references for more general operators $L$ than $(-\Delta)^s$: if $V\geqslant 0$, then $L+V$ generates a sub-Markov semigroup, and if $V\geqslant c>0$, then this semigroup decays exponentially fast, so a non-negative Green's function exists. My favourite reference is [Demuth–van Casteren](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-0348-8460-0).

Comment: @ Mateusz Kwaśnicki The latter result you indicate is interesting! Could you help indicate exactly where it is?